# how to search multiple columns using single search bar in c#

Tags: c#

```
int search = this.tbl_deliveryBindingSource.Find("supplier, invoicenumber", 
                                                         toolStripTextBox1.Text);
this.tbl_deliveryBindingSource.Position = search;
```

Comment: first search for first column if no result yields then search for second column !

Answer (score 0):

Start searching for result in first column, and then if no result are found for second column proceed to second column and so on . . .

You need to prioritize which column it should look for first and then proceed!

Comment: i already did that but what i want is that when i type a data in search bar, the data will show up even though it is not categorized in first column